# PagedList very redundant and repetive code

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, code-duplication, pagedlist

I have the pagedlist on my page and it allows 5 pages to view results results its in the format www.example.com/viewing?1 ... 2 ...3 all the way to 5 and I am checking which page i am on doing

```
@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 1)
{ 
}
```

then

```
@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 2)
{ 
}
```

all the way to 5 .. is there a better way to do this here is the code..

```
// look at Model.article.PageNumber as you can see I use that to get pages 1-5 and
// it keeps the tabs in order if page=2 then the first element is page2 -1 and the like
// how can i reduce this code so i can add the page numbers correctly without repeating 5 times

@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 1)
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber })  @Html.Raw(" ");          
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 2 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 3).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 3 })@Html.Raw(" ");  
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 4).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 4 }) 
}

@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 2)
{  
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber }) @Html.Raw(" ");      
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 2 })@Html.Raw(" "); 
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 3).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 3 })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
}

@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 3)
{  
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 2 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 1 })@Html.Raw(" ");       
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber })@Html.Raw(" "); 
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 2 })  
}

@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 4)
{  
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 3).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 3 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 2 })  @Html.Raw(" ");     
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber + 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber + 1 })  @Html.Raw(" ");
}

@if (Model.article.PageNumber == 5)
{  
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 4).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 4 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 3).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 3 })    @Html.Raw(" ");   
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 2).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 2 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber - 1).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber - 1 }) @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(String.Format("{0}", (Model.article.PageNumber).ToString()), "index", new { page = Model.article.PageNumber })  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are limiting yourself to 5 pages, why does the footer or whatever need to be dynamically generated based on the current page number with a large if/else statement?  You are correct in that this could get unruly quickly, especially if you decide to add more pages in the future to article.

It seems you could pass a single property such as record count or numPages and do the following:

```
@{for(var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= Model.article.numPages, pageNum++){
    @Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0} ", pageNum), "index", new { page = pageNum })                
}}
```

This will reduce the nesting that I see above, removes the need for the Html.Raw at the end and is page agnostic (meaning it doesn't matter what page you are on).  You could also include the current requested page in your view model so that you could not make that page a link.  For example:

```
@{for(var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= Model.article.numPages, pageNum++){
    if(pageNum <> Model.article.PageNumber){
       @Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0} ", pageNum), "index", new { page = pageNum })
    }else{
       @Model.article.PageNumber
    } 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using my PagedList nuget package:

https://github.com/troygoode/pagedlist